# How to pass boolean args into subprocess, when running a script

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using subprocess to run a script. One of the scripts arguments is a boolean. When I try to pass this arg, I get an error.

Here is my code

```
scriptF = 'pythongScript.py'
arg1= 'arg1'
arg2= 'arg2'
arg3= True

subprocess.call(["python", scriptF, "--arg1", file1, "--arg2", file2, "--arg3", arg3])
```

And this is the error message I get

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in call(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    285     retcode = call(["ls", "-l"])
    286     """
--> 287     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    288         try:
    289             return p.wait(timeout=timeout)

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    727                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    728                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 729                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    730         except:
    731             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1293                             errread, errwrite,
   1294                             errpipe_read, errpipe_write,
-> 1295                             restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
   1296                     self._child_created = True
   1297                 finally:

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not bool
```

Comment: typo? `arg3= "True"`: note: subprocess needs lists of strings, bytes, ... as error suggests. Or use `str(arg3)`.

Comment: So it looks like I can only pass in strings? What if the script arg is a boolean?

Comment: just convert all args to strings. But if the argument is a boolean, that generally cals for a switch that is present only if the value is true, absent otherwise. I never saw options where you had to pass `True` or `False` to option `--foo`. Either `--foo` is here (true) or it's not (false)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments

So everything has to be strings. Either a single string or a list of strings. Hence, you could do the following:

```py
scriptF = 'pythongScript.py'
arg1= 'arg1'
arg2= 'arg2'
arg3= True

subprocess.call([
    "python", scriptF, 
    "--arg1", arg1,
    "--arg2", arg2,
    "--arg3" if arg3 else ''
])
```

I assume that in `pythongScript.py` you have an argparse argument that looks like this

```py
parser.add_argument('--arg3', action='store_true')
```

So if `--arg3` is not present it will simply be false and that argument won't be passed to the script